# Improve WordPress performance on large number of posts

Tags: performance

We've 500K+ posts and database is around 3.x GB. (we allocated 5GB innodb buffer pool)
We've been using caching plugin, but performance still sluggish on area where cache is not useful, e.g. wp-admin stuffs.

Are there any more optimisation tips?

Comment: Imposible to answer your question without knowing where your bottle neck is, what the features of your server are and so on. Vote to close as too board.

Answer (score 0):

You could activate the Query Monitor plugin and then load the post(s) / page(s) that are giving you trouble. It will show you where the slowness is being caused, core, theme, plugin A or Plugin B.

It is often possible to speed up a slow query by adding the appropriate index. Try reading **[this article](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)** for tips on how to do this.

Anything more specific will require much more information from you on exactly what is wrong. Details, details.